# Drupal. Redirect to default language front page

Tags: drupal, redirect

How I can redirect users to home page in default language? For example to sait.com/fr from sait.com/ when user almost came.
I tried to use front-page module but he redirects to sait.com//fr/fr instead sait.com/fr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store a cookie variable on client that a user has visited after a comes first time, and before that check if the cookie value is set or not.

Create a custom module and in the hook_init() method of your module, check if the cookie is set, then don't redirect anywhere, if it's not set, set the value and then redirect him to the default language home page.

```
if(!isset($_COOKIE['user_visited])) {
    $_COOKIE['user_visited] = true;
    global $language
    $default_language = variable_get('language_default', $language);
    drupal_goto($default_language->prefix);
}
```

Comment: Your solution redirects to sait.com/fr/fr

Comment: Have you set Path prefix in your default language to "fr"?

Comment: Default language now is English. But prefix for france language is fr

Comment: apologies for the delay yurisnk, I was away. I am able to understand your query now. You need to use primitive redirection here:
remove this line: drupal_goto($default_language->prefix);
add this line: header('location:'. base_path() .'/'. $default_language->prefix);

Comment: I tried to look for something similar to domain_goto() [available for redirecting to other domain in domain module] for languages, no luck yet, will comment again if I find one.

Comment: It seems that I need. But I found oddity inside main menu after this redirect. Link "home" with url=< frontpage > now link to sait.com/fr/fr instead sait.com/fr

Comment: change the default language back to fr

or remove path prefix "fr" for french language if its default

Comment: I set default language to French.
Also I set blank value of "Path prefix language code" for French language. 
But now at sait.com/fr I see "page not found" after redirect.

Comment: Is it possible to alter HREF of link in menu through hook? (replace sait.com/fr/fr to sait.com/fr)